# run a jar command line with maximum resources

Tags: java, memory-management, jar, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to run a jar which works on a 100M rows of records. I hit the GC overlimit. It works for 10M with no issues.

I know the best thing is to find where the overflow occurs

I want to try once to run the jar on the server giving it the maximum resources on heap memory, GC memory etc.

I have tried to run my jar with -xms and -xmc

java -Xmx256m -Xmc256m -jar myapp.jar  //something like that

I want to know how do I run with the maximum resources possible as I dont use this server for any other app.

I have also tried to multi thread using this command

java -jar -Xmx30024m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=12000 myapp.jar

But I am not sure how much this would work.

Can someone suggest me how to overcome this GC error with some limited changes at command line to use maximum resources in the instance.

Comment: it's already using the max resources possible *before* dying with that exception, you really set heap to 30GB and that is still not enough? Also drop that number `ParallelGCThreads` to below 12000

Comment: Are you sure that the records that you're trying to load are all needed in memory at the same time? If not try loading them sequentially i.e. 1 million at a time. Also if memory required to load 100M record is more than the resources on your sever then JVM arguments would do little to help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with the garbage collector, the GC is fast. The GC will only throw this error when you already have [no memory left](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded). 30GB will definitely be enough for 100M records, unless the records are large. What's the size of each record? I would try:

1) Make sure you have 64bit Java, and rerun your code if you used 32bit Java by accident

2) Pull objects out of your innermost loop / optimize out object allocations, I.e.: Use .clear(); don't make a new array. Split an innermost loop that's doing a lot into several different loops with the a fewer amount of objects that need to be allocated per iteration.

3) Try making your work incremental, i.e. use mergesort instead of quicksort. That way you can split the work amongst several instances of 10M record input and save each incremental progress before combining into the 100M answer.

4) Code it in C/C++/Rust, so it uses the stack instead of the heap for temporary variables. If you don't use "new" anywhere in the innermost loop of the Java version, then you might need to compress data usage more. Benchmark memory usage with 5M, 10M, 15M records to get a per-byte impact of each record (Slope of the line going through those three points), and see if you can imagine being able to save each record with fewer bytes if you had control over each byte individually in a systems language (And see if that value is still less than how much RAM you have).

5) If your records are large (>1kb), you definitely want to make a cache. Use a getter to access each record instead of directly from an array, and throttle memory usage. Have the getter access a simple 100M array of references, and limit yourself to having 90M of them being NULL. If you try to access a new record when 10M are already used, then set a random / seldom used existing record to NULL before you access the disk, cache the value, and return the requested record. Make sure your algorithm lends well to this caching (A looser requirement than suggestion #3, but same in principle).